# Is there any way through java program i can tell the Excel to open csv file in utf8?

Tags: java, excel, csv, encoding, utf-8

I am writing data to A.csv file using javacode and then reading A.csv file and writing into DB. I have data in Chinese language and excel is not recognising properly, getting junk values. Is there any way i can tell excel to open the csv file in utf8, so that javacode reads utf8 characters and write it into Db ?

```
public class T {

CSVWriter out = null;

private void write(String[] values) throws IOException {
    out.writeNext(values);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File f  = new File("s.csv");

    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f, false);

    CSVWriter out = new CSVWriter(
        new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(
                os, "UTF-8")));
}
}
```

Comment: Try including a BOM.

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 1):

By default Excel tries to use the user's locale to determine which 8-bit Windows Charset to use when opening a CSV.

By adding a UTF-8 BOM to the top of the file, Excel (Windows and Mac >2013) will open the file in UTF-8 mode.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File f  = new File("s.csv");

    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f, false);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                            os, "UTF-8"));
    bw.write('\ufeff');

    CSVWriter out = new CSVWriter(bw);

    //English, Euro sign, German, Greek
    String[] row = {"hello there","€", "Würzburg", "Αριστοτέλης Τέλλυ Σαβάλας"};

    out.writeNext(row);

    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When Microsoft Excel saves files at CSV UTF-8 it adds three bytes to the beginning of the file. Here is a java static method to accomplish this purpose:

```
  public static void makeFileExcelUTF8(String filename) {
    try {
      Path path = Paths.get(filename);
      byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
      if (fileBytes[0] == (byte) 239 && fileBytes[1] == (byte) 187 && fileBytes[2] == (byte) 191) {
        System.out.println(filename + " is already in excel utf8 format");
        return;
      }
      byte[] prefixBytes = new byte[3];
      prefixBytes[0] = (byte) 239;
      prefixBytes[1] = (byte) 187;
      prefixBytes[2] = (byte) 191;
      Files.write(path, prefixBytes);
      Files.write(path, fileBytes, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("problem saving into excel utf8 format");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The encoding that you're using does not support Chinese letters, however change the UTF-8 to UTF-16, which will suit your solution as it supports Chinese letters.

If you wish to support emojis etc. in future updates, use UTF-32.

Hope that this solves your problem, best.

Comment: The reason for this is the number of bits used to encode each character - more bits, more characters can be represented by the encoding format. UTF supports 8, 16 and 32 bits respectively.

Comment: i am using same code for  almost 25 langaages, since utf8 supports almost all langauges i am using utf8. Does utf-16 supports spanish, and Japanees?

Comment: Okay, think of it as set theory. UTF-32 supports UTF-32 (Obviously), UTF-16 and UTF-8, UTF-16 supports: UTF-16 and UTF-8 but not UTF-32, and UTF8 just supports UTF-8 and not UTF-16 and UTF-32. So if you change the encoding to UTF-16 or 32, then there will be no difference (so to speak) other than being able to support more languages such as Chinese, Japanese, Spanish and more....

Comment: but here the problem is with excel limitation to open csv file in utf8.  Its not opening using utf8, its taking system default encoding. I tried same code on linux, its working, because in linux default encoding is utf8

Comment: @Dan. Your understanding of Unicode encodings is broken - UTF-8 supports **ALL** Unicode encodings including emojis. As does UTF-16 and UTF-32. UTF-8 is variable length encoding. UTF-16 uses 16 bits or
 32 bits per character.   = `\xf0\x9f\x98\x9c` in UTF-8

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack, learning everyday - thank you. Apologies on my behalf, I didn't realise that UTF-8 is variable length, thus assumed that it could only encode ASCII characters.